# What are the methods to prove the correctness of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I want to know the major methods to prove the correctness of a program/algorithm. Recommendations on books are appreciated too. This is a general question. TIA.

Edit: I'm not looking to detailed answer of each and every method. Instead, solicit recommendations/topics to start reading up my own. Name-dropping of methods and brief illustrations of the mainstream methods/resources would be sufficient. This is a newbie question trying to see how expert would advise and point me a right direction.

Comment: This sounds like it might be too broad to me.  Any community votes?  We're looking for narrowly scoped questions that can be answered in one or a few paragraphs.  If one can imagine writing a book on the subject, the question is too broad.  I think you would do best to start by studying standard resources.  For instance, Wikipedia has a few articles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving), and I'm sure there are many books.

Comment: Devour "A Method of Programming" by Edsger W. Dijkstra and W. H. J. Feijen. It is short and highly accessible.

Comment: The CLRS book is pretty good at that.  But otherwise, induction usually works great.  For recursive algorithms, assume by induction that the recursions did their job, and prove that the current recursion works.  For iterative algorithms, apply induction on the number of loops.  For dynamic programming, you have a recurrence $\rightarrow$ induction.  For greedy algorithms, not usually induction - there's the technique of taking the solution with the most common elements as yours and arguing they are equal.

Comment: Testing, testing, testing, and some more testing. When you can't find any bugs, that's the first step done.

Comment: @gnasher729 yeah, the first step, but what about the rest

Comment: see https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask